# Outlook sorting rule based on "buried" email header info?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016, headers, rules, email-filter

My employer has a contract with an anti-spam educational company. This company (let's call them spam4u) sends multiple fake "spam" and "phishing" emails each week to test whether I will fall for the trap or not. The problem is, is that now 100% of my spam is coming from this company -_-.

I know these spam messages are fake because I can find the company's name embedded within the header information of each email (despite them being from multiple senders from endlessly variable domains, sent at different times of day, and sent with different subjects and bodies).

I know the efforts have noble intentions, but I *need to make these stop*. My IT department said it's out of their hands, so I've got to find a personal solution to this nuisance.

Given that the only "marker" (indication) that these emails are all related is buried in obscure portions of the header info, I cannot figure out if there's a way to block them or create an email rule.

**IS there a way to create email rules based on information "buried" in the header info** that doesn't belong to sender, recipient, subject, date, or body?

I'm using Outlook 2016 on a Windows 10 machine. (I tend to use Outlook online, but I go back and forth between online and desktop app -- so a solution to either would work.)

Comment: Outlook has a rule for specific words in Message Header. Try finding "spam4u" in this.

Comment: @John I'm not seeing that. The rules option online is giving me the choice to add a condition to the following fields: To, From, CC, Subject, Body, sender address, recipient address, importance, sensitivity, classification, flag, type, message size, and date received

Comment: @John...Annnnnddddd when I learn to read the one line that for some reason has been invisible to me all day, Outlook also provides the option of "message header". DOH! -_-  . Thanks for making me take an umteenth look at this, John!

Comment: When you went to Rules, did you click on "Advanced"?  Outlook has many, many Rules to select from

Comment: Please let me know if I have answered your question and I will post a proper answer.

Comment: @John I don't see an option for"Advanced," but as I mentioned in my last comment, it looks like I found what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: Outlook rules with conditions of "with specific words in message header" should be helpful to your issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Outlook 2016 has many Rules in its Rule engine. It has a rule for specific words in Message Header. Try finding "spam4u" in this.

Outlook, Main Ribbon, Rules, Create Rule.

Please see the screen shot below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to provide the method for doing this using the web version of outlook:

1. Click settings (gear symbol) at top right of window
2. Select "view all Outlook Settings"
3. Select the "Rules" tab and then click "Add New Rule"
4. Under the drop-down for "Add a Condition", there's the option of "**Message header includes**" under the *Keywords* category of conditions.
5. Select this option and then type text you want to search for in the header.

[image]